# Regarding question migrated to Arduino S.E

Tags: discussion, migration, arduino

I just noticed that [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/748/470) has been migrated (two hours ago) from electrical engineering S.E. to the Arduino S.E.

Can someone please explain the reasoning behind that decision when

- The question had already received a reply in electrical engineering S.E. (two days ago)
- There is a general S.E. policy to [NOT migrate](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5780) questions in beta sites
- The question is on topic in electrical engineering S.E.

Answer (score 3):

Although [that question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/748/is-my-arduino-destroyed-or-are-the-pins-destroyed) doesn't reflect it right now, it was closed as *Off-Topic > Repair* by community moderation here on EE.SE.  It remained closed to 2 days.
I have asked an Arduino.SE mod for permission to migrate it.  They weren't against that.
I have migrated it.

Comment: Considering we just reiterated the policy http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/migration-guidelines-re-arduinos did you even confer with the other mods?

Comment: I'd rather have a question alive on Arduino.SE than dead on EE.SE if Arduino.SE will have it. There's been enough of petty brigading against Arduino questions on EE.SE, and pointless bureaucratic "conferring", elitism and decision-by-committee to no merit. I call BS on any recommendation that "we'd rather kill the question than migrate it". EE.SE doesn't want something, Arduino.SE does, stop being petulant and let them have it.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh yea, after all, rules are pointless right?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh The question shouldn't be closed in the first place, and a moderator could easily have reopened it. Like it or not (some members don't) Arduino related questions are perfectly on topic in E.E. S.E. If a member wants to ask a question in Arduino S.E. that is fine but when he decides to ask it in E.E. (having any right since it is on topic) we can't decide for him to move it. Nick Alexeev, you said you have asked a moderator there if he wanted the question, but what came before that was a decision that moderator(s) didn't want the question here, or else you wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @Passerby In a community-operated platform, rules are an ever-evolving framework. Certain people's attitudes clearly are not. Given past history, I won't waste energy debating it with you.

Comment: I was just about to up-vote your newly posted reply about todays migrated question, but you removed it before I had a chance to do so. Unlike the one I originally referred to, it seems ok since the OP requested the action; although he could have just deleted the question from E.E. S.E. and repost in Arduino S.E with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

That question clearly doesn't belong here.  There are several problems with it on EE.SE:

It is a high level user issue, not really about electronics.  The OP is at the level of connecting a bluetooth block and a arduino block.  If you can't draw a schematic from the question, just a block diagram, then it's probably off topic.

There is no evidence the OP is interested in or wants to actually understand the electronics.  This is simply *make it work for me*, the electronics equivalent of *giv me da codz*.

As a aside, this is really why most arduino questions don't belong here.  It's not the arduino that makes them off topic specifically, but that those asking arduino questions are likely to not be interested in the electronics.

Much very basic, and what should be obvious, information is missing.  The only symptom is *"didn't work"* and that certain pins *"aren't working"*.  Not only that, we have no idea what those pins are, or even which component of the block diagram they belong to.  Perhaps some of this would be implied context on a arduino site, but certainly not here.

The writing, while still decipherable, isn't doing the post any favors.  This isn't a reason to close on its own, but it does add a little annoyance, which would tip it over the edge if someone is right at the cusp of deciding about downvoting or closing.  We get a lot worse than this regularly, and this isn't all *that* bad.  But, presentation matters, a lot.  Never understimate how sloppy presentation is a slap in the face of anyone you present to, especially when you are asking for a favor.

This post was correctly closed here.  Therefore migrating it to arduino.SE with the permission of the mods there was a reasonable action.

Comment: Any damage to the mcu is probably related to exceeding proper operating conditions, in my opinion that is related to electronic engineering. Even if the OP isn't interested in that (maybe because he is not aware of it), it's not a cause to ignore the question or get rid of it. Regarding the quality of the question, if it was of a low quality then migrating it in a beta forum is even worse than migrating a proper question. We can't treat Arduino S.E. as a dumpster for bad questions. Also the approval of an inexperienced moderator to accept the question doesn't really justify the action.

Comment: @alexan: The Arduino site wasn't used as a dumpster if they were asked first if they wanted the question and then said they did.

Comment: I think everything that needs to be said regarding the migration of Arduino questions can be found in [this post]( http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/migration-guidelines-re-arduinos). The willingness of an Arduino S.E moderator to accept a question doesn't change anything (neither does the will of anyone to get rid of such questions). It's been two days since the migration, and the only reply given is still the one that has been given in E.E. S.E. So I wonder what was the benefit of the migration apart from maybe increasing the question count in Arduino S.E.

Answer (score 0):

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/arduino-mega-not-flashable-with-xbee-pro-s2b
3x close votes *Off Topic > Use*
O.P. requested migration
I have asked an Arduino.SE mod for permission to migrate it. They weren't against that.
I have migrated it.

Comment: Unlike the migrated question I originally referred to, the migration of this one seems ok since the OP requested the action; although he could have just deleted the question from E.E. S.E. and repost in Arduino S.E with the same result. I'll up-vote the action.